# Laravel with SQL Server ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server Login timeout expired

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, docker, ubuntu

I am working on a project which requires Laravel + SQL Server.
I was trying to build the environment by using Laravel sail, and realized that the dockerfile used by sail does not contains drivers for SQL Server. This leads to an issue of `cannot find driver` when doing migrations or other operations trying to access the database.

Now I think I fixed the driver issue above (maybe), by adding dependencies to the dockerfile. However, a new problem appears: when I try to run migration I will get this timeout error:

```sh
sail artisan migrate

  Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HYT00]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (SQL: select * from sys.sysobjects where id = object_id(migrations) and xtype in ('U', 'V'))
```

The database is possible to be accessed and execute queries, and docker is running without any error message.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  laravel.test:
    build:
      context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        WWWGROUP: "${WWWGROUP}"
    image: sail-8.0/app
    container_name: "app"
    ports:
      - "${APP_PORT:-80}:80"
    environment:
      WWWUSER: "${WWWUSER}"
      LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
    volumes:
      - ".:/var/www/html"
    networks:
      - sail
    depends_on:
      - sqlserver

  sqlserver:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    container_name: sqlserver
    ports:
      - "${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-1433}:1433"
    environment:
      MSSQL_PID: "Express"
      MSSQL_DATABASE: "master"
      SA_PASSWORD: "yourStrong(!)Password"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    volumes:
      - "sailmssql:/var/opt/mssql"
    networks:
      - sail

networks:
  sail:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  sailmssql:
    driver: local
```

Here is the edited dockerfile:

```yaml
FROM ubuntu:20.04

LABEL maintainer="Taylor Otwell"

ARG WWWGROUP

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2 \
  && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg \
  && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg \
  && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
  && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C \
  && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C \
  && echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y php8.0-cli php8.0-dev \
  php8.0-pgsql php8.0-sqlite3 php8.0-gd \
  php8.0-curl php8.0-memcached \
  php8.0-imap php8.0-mysql php8.0-mbstring \
  php8.0-xml php8.0-zip php8.0-bcmath php8.0-soap \
  php8.0-intl php8.0-readline \
  php8.0-msgpack php8.0-igbinary php8.0-ldap \
  php8.0-redis \
  && php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
  && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash - \
  && apt-get install -y nodejs \
  && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y yarn \
  && apt-get install -y mysql-client \
  && apt-get install -y postgresql-client \

  # add sql server dependency
  && apt-get install -y sudo \
  && sudo su \
  && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
  && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
  && sudo apt-get update \
  && sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 mssql-tools\
  && sudo apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev \ 
  # end

  && apt-get -y autoremove \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN pecl channel-update https://pecl.php.net/channel.xml \
  && pecl install swoole \

  # install sql server driver
  && pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv \
  # && echo "extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so\nextension=sqlsrv.so\nextension=swoole.so" >> php.ini \

  && pecl clear-cache \
  && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/bin/php8.0

RUN groupadd --force -g $WWWGROUP sail
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g $WWWGROUP -u 1337 sail

COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY php.ini /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container \

  # enable driver on php.ini file
  && echo "extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so\nextension=sqlsrv.so" >> /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

I thought it was the password problem but it shows the same error when I change the password, so I believe this happens before the credential validation.

Also tried to change same env settings such as `DB_HOST` to 127.0.0.1 or localhost.

I did a lot of googling and research but could not figure out the problem, does anyone has any idea about this issue?

Comment: Did you had any luck solving this issue?

Comment: Have you solved?